# Counting number of classes and append it as number in a div

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a number of images. Now each image has a class and many images has the same class. Now I want to loop through each image, collect its class and count the number of images  with a specific class...

HTML:

```
<div id="articleThumb">
    <ul id="makeThumb">
            <li>
                <img class="merc" src="../img/items/merc_sedan.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="merc" src="../img/items/merc_sedan2.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="bmw" src="../img/items/bmw_sedan.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="bmw" src="../img/items/bmw_hatchback.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="bmw" src="../img/items/bmw_sedan3.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="ford" src="../img/items/ford_sedan.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="ford" src="../img/items/ford_hatchback.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="ford" src="../img/items/ford_bakkie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="ford" src="../img/items/ford_suv.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="mit" src="../img/items/mit_sedan.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="merc" src="../img/items/merc_suv.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="bmw" src="../img/items/bmw_suv.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="bmw" src="../img/items/bmw_suv2.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="mit" src="../img/items/mit_suv.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="mit" src="../img/items/mit_bakkie.jpg" />
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I know I can use:

```
$('.bmw').length;
```

to count the number of images with class .bmw, but that is not so efficient if you have 300 classes.

**What I would like to do is determine the class with jQuery(not specified by me) and count it like that:**

```
 $('#articleThumb ul li img').each(function () {
                var y = $(this).attr('class');
                var allClasses = [y];
            });
```

Now count all the classes and append each class's count to its matching display div...

```
var countEachClass = allClasses.length;
$(countEachClass).appendTo('#count .' + [y]);

<div id="count">
    <div class="bmw">number calculated by .length</div>
    <div class="merc">number calculated by .length</div>
    <div class="ford">number calculated by .length</div>
    ...etc
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
I want to replace the #count div with the **following** to display the numbers:

```
                 <article class="make">
                    <div class="content">
                       <h4><a class="merc" href="#latestClick">Mercedes-Benz</a></h4>
                       <div class="date">12 March 2013</div>
                       <div class="count">THE  NUMBER HERE</div>
                    </div>
                 </article>
                 <article class="make latest">
                    <div class="content">
                       <h4><a class="bmw" href="#latestClick">BMW</a></h4>
                       <div class="date">12 March 2013</div>
                       <div class="count">THE NUMBER HERE</div>
                    </div>
                 </article>
```

**ANSWER:** http://jsfiddle.net/YNqGR/9/

Comment: Please stop adding greetings and signatures to posts.

Comment: I actually got a vote from one guy thanking me for my good manner...But I guess not all people like it hey... So I don't know if it is good practice here or not...One person likes it another dislikes it...So what do you recommend I do?

Comment: What's wrong with saying hi to everyone? Some of us here might not have had a good day...

Comment: But fair, I see that the moderator removed it, so i won't do it again...

Comment: That person was wrong to upvote. Whilst I'm a massive fan of manners, they are not a reason to upvote a post.

Comment: So what should I do then? Greet or be indifferent about it?

Comment: Jump straight into the question! Nobody has any reason to assume your not a nice guy so saying 'Hi' and 'Thanks' won't make a difference. Besides, it's usually quite easy to see how much you respect the community by how you write the question

Comment: See here for the "official" guidelines regarding greetings and stuff: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/142802.

Comment: Note that the greeting ban is not just a matter of opinion. Most greetings like "hi" and "hello" are removed *automatically* from posts. You just happened to find one that the automation doesn't recognize as a greeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an object with the class name as key and the counter as value:

```
var map = {};

$('#articleThumb ul li img').each(function () {
    map[this.className] = (map[this.className] || 0) + 1;
});
```

Now you can iterate over the object and do whatever you want with it. Note that this will only work if each image has only one class.

Appending to the other element would just be:

```
$('#count').children().text(function() {
    return map[this.className] || 0;
});
```

If the elements don't exist yet, you have to create them as well:

```
var $count = $('#count');
$.each(map, function(cls, count) {
    $count.append($('<div />', {'class': cls, text: count}));
});
```

---

And actually, the last update also made me realize that if the elements already exist, you could just do:

```
var $images = $('#articleThumb ul li img');
$('#count').children().text(function() {
    return $images.filter('.' + this.className).length;
});
```

There are many ways.

Comment: how do I actually display/append the values then?

Comment: Thank you Felix, perfect, it works. But what if I change the display from the #count div to a new layout? (SEE UPDATE...)

Comment: Well, then you have to find the `a` element for each class, traverse up to the `.content` element and down again to the `.count` element. Have a look at jQuery's traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/.

Comment: I understand what you mean but cannot quite execute it: http://jsfiddle.net/YNqGR/8/

Comment: The HTML in the example is different again. I updated it in some way, don't know if that's what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/YNqGR/9/.

Comment: Exactly what I want - Thank you so much Felix...I can learn a lot form this

Answer (score 1):

If you know up front what the classes will be, you could store them in an array like this:

```
var types = ['merc', 'bmw', 'mit', 'ford'];

$.each(types, function (i, type) {
    $('div.' + type).html( $('img.' + type).length );
});
```

Comment: thank you misterkeg, but that is not the purpose. So everytime a class is added, I need to add that class(manually) to the array. That is tedious and not the answer I was looking for